# Why Mongodb insert performance become so slow after a while

Tags: mongodb

I am inserting 100 million data into Mongodb using Java API (with 50% columns are indexed, not bulk insert due to business logic).

Table and index structure:

```
db.gm_std_measurements.findOne();
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("530b6340e4b033fabd61fb99"),
    "fkDataSeriesId" : 421,
    "measDateUtc" : "2014-10-10 12:00:00",
    "measDateSite" : "2014-03-15 12:00:00",
    "project_id" : 379,
    "measvalue" : 597.516583008608,
    "refMeas" : false,
    "reliability" : 1
}

db.gm_std_measurements.getIndexes();
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "testdb.gm_std_measurements",
        "name" : "_id_"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "fkDataSeriesId" : 1,
            "measDateUtc" : 1,
            "measDateSite" : 1,
            "project_id" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "testdb.gm_std_measurements",
        "name" : "default_mongodb_test_index"
    }
]
```

At beginning mongostat tells the speed is quite good, for about 20-30k inserts per seconds. But afterward a while the performance drops down really quickly, with system load 5-10. What could be the reason?

As observed, for a lot of times, the mongostat seems to be frozen (or mongod is frozen), because there is no insert at all, and the tracing data of "locked db" is also 0.0%, is that normal?

Thanks a lot!

Below is some output of the mongostat:

```
insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res faults    locked db idx miss %     qr|qw   ar|aw  netIn netOut  conn       time 
 39520     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0   160m   506m    67m      3 testdb:61.6%          0       0|0     0|1     9m     2k     4   15:58:26 
 36010     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0   160m   506m    83m      1 testdb:55.9%          0       0|0     0|0     8m     2k     4   15:58:27 
 33793     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0   288m   762m    92m      3 testdb:57.8%          0       0|0     0|0     7m     2k     4   15:58:28 
 32061     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0   288m   762m   113m      0 testdb:55.9%          0       0|0     0|0     7m     2k     4   15:58:29 
 32302     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0   288m   762m   110m      1 testdb:60.2%          0       0|0     0|1     7m     2k     4   15:58:30 
 31283     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0   288m   762m   138m      0 testdb:57.1%          0       0|0     0|1     7m     2k     4   15:58:31 
  1126     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0   544m  1.25g   367m      0  testdb:3.4%          0       0|0     0|1   258k     2k     4   15:58:55 
insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res faults    locked db idx miss %     qr|qw   ar|aw  netIn netOut  conn       time 
 18330     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0   544m  1.25g   369m      1 testdb:40.8%          0       0|0     0|1     4m     2k     4   15:58:56 
  4235     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0   544m  1.25g   395m      0  testdb:7.3%          0       0|0     0|1   974k     2k     4   15:58:57 
    *0     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0   544m  1.25g   395m      0  testdb:0.0%          0       0|0     0|1    62b     2k     4   15:58:58 
    *0     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0   544m  1.25g   395m      0  testdb:0.0%          0       0|0     0|1    62b     2k     4   15:58:59 
    *0     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0   544m  1.25g   395m      0  testdb:0.0%          0       0|0     0|1    62b     2k     4   15:59:00 
    *0     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0   544m  1.25g   395m      0  testdb:0.0%          0       0|0     0|1    62b     2k     4   15:59:01 
    *0     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0   544m  1.25g   395m      0  testdb:0.0%          0       0|0     0|1    62b     2k     4   15:59:02 
    *0     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0   544m  1.25g   395m      0  testdb:0.0%          0       0|0     0|1    62b     2k     4   15:59:04 
 20083     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0   544m  1.25g   378m      0      .:23.4%          0       0|0     0|1     4m     2k     4   15:59:05 
 28595     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0   544m  1.25g   404m      0 testdb:60.0%          0       0|0     0|0     6m     2k     4   15:59:06 
insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res faults    locked db idx miss %     qr|qw   ar|aw  netIn netOut  conn       time 
 26415     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0   544m  1.25g   381m      0 testdb:60.8%          0       0|0     0|1     6m     2k     4   15:59:07 
 27161     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0   544m  1.25g   411m      0 testdb:59.5%          0       0|0     0|1     6m     2k     4   15:59:08 
 25550     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0   544m  1.25g   397m      0 testdb:56.6%          0       0|0     0|1     5m     2k     4   15:59:09 
 26245     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0   544m  1.25g   429m      0 testdb:60.0%          0       0|0     0|1     6m     2k     4   15:59:10 
 27836     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0   544m  1.25g   444m      0 testdb:60.0%          0       0|0     0|1     6m     2k     4   15:59:11 
 27041     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0   544m  1.25g   422m      0 testdb:62.2%          0       0|0     0|1     6m     2k     4   15:59:12 
 26522     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0   544m  1.25g   463m      0 testdb:58.4%          0       0|0     0|1     6m     2k     4   15:59:13 
 27195     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0   544m  1.25g   475m      0 testdb:60.1%          0       0|0     0|1     6m     2k     4   15:59:14 
 25610     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0  1.03g  2.25g   500m      1 testdb:57.6%          0       0|0     0|1     5m     2k     4   15:59:15 
 25501     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0  1.03g  2.25g   474m      0 testdb:64.7%          0       0|0     0|1     5m     2k     4   15:59:16 
insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res faults    locked db idx miss %     qr|qw   ar|aw  netIn netOut  conn       time 
 27446     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0  1.03g  2.25g   489m      0 testdb:58.2%          0       0|1     0|1     6m     2k     4   15:59:17 
 27113     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0  1.03g  2.25g   515m      1 testdb:57.2%          0       0|1     0|1     6m     2k     4   15:59:18 
 25383     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0  1.03g  2.25g   524m      0 testdb:59.9%          0       0|0     0|1     5m     2k     4   15:59:19 
 27506     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0  1.03g  2.25g   546m      1 testdb:61.3%          0       0|0     0|1     6m     2k     4   15:59:20 
 14901      2     *0     *0       0     1|0       0  1.03g  2.25g   498m      0 testdb:32.8%          0       0|1     0|1     3m     2k     4   15:59:21 
  9026     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0  1.03g  2.25g   501m      0      .:62.5%          0       0|1     0|1     2m     2k     4   15:59:24 
 16834     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       1  1.03g  2.25g   506m      0      .:73.9%          0       0|1     0|1     3m     3k     4   15:59:25 
 25975     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0  1.03g  2.25g   521m      0 testdb:60.8%          0       0|0     0|1     5m     2k     4   15:59:26 
 23389     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0  1.03g  2.25g   525m      0 testdb:58.4%          0       0|0     0|1     5m     2k     4   15:59:27 
 27226     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0  1.03g  2.25g   584m      0 testdb:55.0%          0       0|0     0|1     6m     2k     4   15:59:28 
insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res faults    locked db idx miss %     qr|qw   ar|aw  netIn netOut  conn       time 
 26362     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0  1.03g  2.25g   541m      0 testdb:56.3%          0       0|1     0|1     6m     2k     4   15:59:31 
  2658     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0  1.03g  2.25g   564m      0      .:64.2%          0       0|0     0|1   611k     3k     4   15:59:32 
    *0     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0  1.03g  2.25g   564m      0  testdb:0.0%          0       0|0     0|1    62b     2k     4   15:59:34 
    *0     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0  1.03g  2.25g   564m      0  testdb:0.0%          0       0|0     0|1    62b     2k     4   15:59:35 
    *0     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0  1.03g  2.25g   564m      0  testdb:0.0%          0       0|0     0|1    62b     2k     4   15:59:36 
  2777     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0  1.03g  2.25g   583m      0  testdb:4.8%          0       0|0     0|1   638k     2k     4   15:59:37 
    *0     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0  1.03g  2.25g   584m      0  testdb:0.0%          0       0|0     0|1    62b     2k     4   15:59:38 
    *0     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0  1.03g  2.25g   584m      0  testdb:0.0%          0       0|0     0|1    62b     2k     4   15:59:39 
    *0     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0  1.03g  2.25g   584m      0  testdb:0.0%          0       0|0     0|1    62b     2k     4   15:59:40 
    *0     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0  1.03g  2.25g   584m      0  testdb:0.0%          0       0|0     0|1    62b     2k     4   15:59:41 
insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res faults    locked db idx miss %     qr|qw   ar|aw  netIn netOut  conn       time 
    *0     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0  1.03g  2.25g   584m      0  testdb:0.0%          0       0|0     0|1    62b     2k     4   15:59:42 
 19823     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0  1.03g  2.25g   549m      0 testdb:57.8%          0       0|1     0|1     4m     2k     4   15:59:43 
 25267     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0  1.03g  2.25g   561m      0 testdb:60.4%          0       0|0     0|1     5m     2k     4   15:59:44 
 26489     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0  1.03g  2.25g   601m      0 testdb:58.8%          0       0|0     0|1     6m     2k     4   15:59:45 
 26516     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0  1.03g  2.25g   604m      0 testdb:58.4%          0       0|0     0|1     1m     2k     4   16:00:26 
   *0     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0  2.03g  4.25g   868m      0  testdb:0.0%          0       0|0     0|1    62b     2k     4   16:00:27 
   *0     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0  2.03g  4.25g   868m      0  testdb:0.0%          0       0|0     0|1    62b     2k     4   16:00:33 
 2775     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0  2.03g  4.25g   845m      0  testdb:0.8%          0       0|1     0|1   638k     3k     4   16:00:34 
 3886     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0  2.03g  4.25g   879m      0      .:30.5%          0       0|0     0|1   893k     2k     4   16:00:35
```

Comment: "what could be the reason" - quite likely, the indexes.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, you mean during the index writting/updating, the insert rate would be 0?

Comment: When you insert a document, all indexes are updated. The more indexes you have (and larger they are), the slower writes are.

Comment: I have updated my table and index structure.

Comment: The things are wired that, for sometimes the insert rate is 0, and it lasts quite some time and appear more and more often. If it the index update, I suppose only the insert rate will be slowed down, but should be stable. In my case it seems that something else has stopped the mongod...

Comment: May it be a memory issue ? Are you running mongo in a x86 process ?

Comment: I am running on a 64bit Opensuse, with 8 cores and 32G memory. The majority of the memory is still free.

Comment: My money is on your disk flush time, caused by your indexes.  By default, mongo flushes changes to disk every 60 seconds.  You indexes will be all over your shell files, so it will likely have quite a few to flush every time.  You can use mongostat to check on the flushms param

Comment: note that during "idle" times the db is not just idle but getting nothing from the app.  if this is Java are you sure it's not doing something like garbage collection and not generating any inserts during that time?  are you logging any timings in the application?

Comment: What was being hinted at right at the start by @SergioTulentsev is **drop all** of your indexes while you are bulk loading, as the process will not need to **grow** indexes as well as your data under this kind of load. At the end of this, add your indexes, which if you ask it to, can be a [background](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/build-indexes-in-the-background/) operation

Comment: @dnlbmn, i noticed the index might be the issue. But since I need the index anyway, maybe a flush to disk per minute is acceptable? Even when there is a lot of index to flush per minute?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky, thanks for your hints, I make some updated replies to this post with new test.

Comment: @NeilLunn, i am not quite sure about your proposal, you mean make insert through bulk insert but without index update? then add/update index once all insert done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try dropping the indexes and then perform the insert, after the insert is finished you can then create the indexes. I think this will be an overall faster scenario.

You can also recreate the indexes at the background

```
db.collection.ensureIndex( { a: 1 }, { background: true } )
```

if you want to continue querying, but that will make index creation slower